# Experience manager - Update preview loop with "Could not remove the storageTransactionId" in logs

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1, updatepreview

I'm seeing an issue with experience manager on 2013 SP1. When opening a page in XPM I am repeatedly seeing this classic warning:

[image]

On clicking the update button the page reloads but the same warning is presented.

If I look in the webservice logs I see no errors and just these warnings:

`2015-09-04 14:00:35,854 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId a2a579c8-a888-4d14-bade-20e9f7cfc28e from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,607 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId 0b6d34bb-3ea8-40d7-8edf-633b0ed23701 from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,648 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId d1686166-a626-4e8e-8196-2207db66822f from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,672 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId e1e292aa-5987-4e89-b37d-d0348e3e3805 from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,713 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId 14d83d67-ffe9-46d1-a4cf-59d8af38e2af from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,756 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId 7410074e-0705-439c-97de-9248075565c7 from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,797 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId 36a0e348-bb7f-430c-bb16-fbdd636de699 from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,836 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId 7e4798c9-2f3d-4b00-94cd-9130d7dade0a from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,868 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId 954d5290-0836-4ef6-b047-ac36ed2888e8 from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,901 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId ad22e2b4-9a6f-4f82-baa0-3686a81d0e0c from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,963 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId 2659582a-26e3-4044-b58e-b7b33992e5fa from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:37,987 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId ab48db82-f486-4e26-aa8f-8ca3da758c71 from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:38,024 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId f0da599d-503b-4b4b-a236-2cdfb3736b93 from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null
2015-09-04 14:01:38,059 WARN  LocalThreadTransaction - Could not remove the storageTransactionId b96bc4fd-47b2-4926-9882-c2682190c93b from the current thread, because there was another storageTransactionId: null`

Can anyone offer any insight into what the problem may be?

Comment: I have seen this same WARN in the web application logs, but without the error message in the GUI (SDL Web 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into the session wrapper configuration under cd_storage file in the web application that you are using to enable experience manager and ensure that the wrapper has same machine name give for all the nodes in the NLB for the web application. Same is true for ExperienceManager AKA Session_Preview service configuration file.

Add the below in the cd_storage file under Session Wrappers.

```
<MachineName>thisshuldbesamemachineacrossNLBservers</MachineName>
```

This could be one of the reasons why the storage transaction ids are having issues. Also, did you check that the CM is getting updated when you make changes via Experience Manager and the web app is also showing updated content if you do finish editing to atleast zero down on "Update Preview" being the only issue and not editing, saving and publishing?